# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." SQL Connection failing on .Open()

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB app that uses a SQL Server database.

The issue I am having is that users are no longer able to login from the website.
However, when I run locally against the same database, it works just fine.

I have gone through the logs and determined its the `SqlConnection()` object that is throwing the

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

error once `oCn.Open()`  is called.

```
    Public Function ValidLogin(ByVal EmpNum As String, ByVal Password As String, ByRef ErrMsg As String) As Boolean

    Dim oCn As New SqlConnection(GetAPP2Password())
    Dim oDr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    Dim oCmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim sResponse As String = ""
    ErrMsg = ""
    Try
        oCn.Open()
        // do whatever else i need to do
    Finally
        oDr.Close()
        oCn.Close()
        oCmd.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return sResponse = "VALID"

Public Function GetAPP2Password() As String
    Return sAPP2Password
End Function
```

this is the function that sets "sAPP2Password"

```
Public Function LoadPasswordString(ByVal databaseName As String) As String
    'Reads a given setting from the <appSettings> section in the Web.config file.
    'The setting key is prefixed with the current HostName to enable us to have one
    'Web.config file that works for DVLP,ACPT and PROD with no mods required when
    'moving between environments.
    Dim strReturn As String = ""
    Dim cc As New CECCoupler
    strReturn = cc.getSecret(databaseName)
    If InStr(strReturn, "Error:") Then ' check strReturn for ERROR
        LogEvent("Globals.vb", "System", "Localhost", strReturn)
    End If
    Return strReturn
End Function
```

I am trying to figure out what the issue is on the application so I can get users back to logging in to the site.

below is the logged error from the application

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at APP.APP2DataAccess.ValidLogin(String EmpNum, String Password, String& ErrMsg)
> at APP.Login.cmdLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Thats a code error, not a database error. Somewhere you aren't checking that a object exists. We can't see what this is with the limited code provided.

Comment: I've made some updates. Hopefully this gives more insight.